# How to get all base interface property only in typescript or javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two interfaces as below:

```
interface PublicUser {
    userId? : string
    name? : string
}

interface User extends PublicUser{
    email? : string
    phonenumber? : string
}
```

All data are stored as User in database. What I want to do is removing private properties from User data. So I am doing like below:

```
const user = serverData as User;

let visibleUser : PublicUser = PublicUser()
if(user.userId)  visibleUser.userId = user.userId
if(user.name)  visibleUser.name = user.name

sendPublicProfileToAnyone(visibleUser);
```

I don't think this is good solution. Because what if there is another public property like age. There must be a way I can only get all PublicUser properties from full dataset.

Comment: What is `PublicUser()`?

Comment: There is no introspection of TypeScript interfaces at runtime. All you can do is write code in a way that will fail to compile when you add more properties to the interface, and force you to update your code accordingly.